# Error while trying to add image to react project

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I am working on a react project. I am trying to add an image to one of my components. I made a directory named "images" in my project structure tree and I have put my image in this directory (image of project structure is attached below). I want to pass this image as src to my img tag. For this I right clicked on image and selected "copy image path" and then pasted that path to src of img tag. But when I try to run it, I get an error saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Here is my code of component and screenshot of project structure.

P.S. I am on Ubuntu Environment

```
export default class CustomizedAppComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <img src="/home/user/Documents/Tessact-Master/dev/js/images/logo.png"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: try `src='./dev/js/images/logo.png'`

Comment: That looks like a system path from root. React is a server and therefore uses the http protocol from the root of the react project.

Comment: How do you serve your app? And how do you preview it in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need to use ../ or require in your url.. **SIMPLE TRICK**: It is very important from where you are serving you app. If you are serving your app from **Tessact-Master** then you code should be like this below

use just `/dev` not `./dev`

```
export default class CustomizedAppComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={"/dev/js/images/logo.png"}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This Worked. Thanks

Comment: @user3761761 It is good to upvote a perfect answer for your solution. It helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the src of the image must be relative to the location of the component it is used in. Assuming the `CustomizedAppComponent` to be in the `components` or `containers` folder your image path must look like

```
 "../images/logo.png"/
```

if the component is again inside another folder inside folder `components`, then give path as

```
"../../images/logo.png"/             // add '../' so on
```

Also in react you may need to mention the src within a `require` if you are using webpack to transpile your jsx and if not and then `omit require` in the below code.

```
export default class CustomizedAppComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={require("../images/logo.png")}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to use the require. That will crash your JS.

Comment: @JF Why will it crash my JS. I don't see it happening in my case.

Comment: If you `require()` an image file, there will be an invalid syntax error because the binary file is not valid JS. `require()` loads the file at the given path, executes it, and returns the `module.exports` object.

Comment: @JF I have been using this syntax for a long time and never faced any issue with ti

Comment: @JF have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images. OP did not specify explicitly what he is using to compile the JSX.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that!