# My image is not shown in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

This is a Component of my App, it has a image  that has not got output, i think the src is right, my files tree is:

1. App:

   2. src:
      3.1 images
      3.2 bull.jpg
      3.2 utils
      3.3 Carta.js

this code is from Carta.js that have got the Image:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Carta.css'
import FlipCard from 'react-flipcard';


export default class Carta extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
           <div className="carta" onClick={this.props.seleccionarCarta}>
                <FlipCard
                     flipped={this.props.estaSiendoComparada || this.props.fueAdivinada}
                     disabled={true}
                  >
                    <div className="portada"></div>
                    <div className="contenido">
                        <ul>    
                            <li><img src={"images/toro.jpg"} alt={''} /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </FlipCard>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380054/error-while-trying-to-add-image-to-react-project/40380431#40380431

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably due to incorrect path. This is because your src structure might be different than the build structure, which is the structure generated by webpack.

Importing image may add an extra load to the bundle, but [doing this will ensure that webpack move the images into the build folder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files), and give the correct paths.

If images is in the same folder as Carta.js, then the src should have ./ at the beginning.

```
import MyImage from './images/toro.jpg'

// ...rest of your code

<img src={MyImage} />
```

Comment: ¿Why import it if you can just reference it? It should increase bundle size, as far as I know is not the best practice.
Please, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Nevermind about my previous answer. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still having no output, the src doesnt  found the image, idk why

Comment: is your directory called 'Images' and not 'images'? Also is it on the same folder as Carta.js?

Comment: images its all in lower case

Comment: i dont know why the image is not shown, i put the image bull.jpg in the same folder as Carta.js and use the path "./bull.jpg" and still hasnt got an output