# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '***.jpg'

Tags: reactjs

I want to use `img src=` to show the image, but eventually failed. I have tried the following methods, but none of these worked:

1.

```
var  logo = require('img/logo.jpg');
...
<img src={logo} alt="" />
```

2.

```
import logo from 'style/ydg_logo.jpg';
...
<img src={logo} alt="" />
```

3.

```
<img src={require('img/logo.jpg')} alt="" />
```

Error:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'style/ydg_logo.jpg'

Comment: whats the error when using 3rd one ??

Comment: What are you using the transpile and build your code?

Comment: check this may be it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

include `file-loader` in package.json, and use loaders to load file in webpack.config.js

`{ test: /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/,loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }`