# React/Javascript Load all image file paths from public/images folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple app which is supposed to show all images in a specific folder. As far as I understand, javascript is not allowed to load local files. Is this correct? Is it possible to load all images file paths from the public/images folder into an array?

Thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder  it might be help you.

Comment: This only loads a specific image. I want all images in this folder without knowing the file name

Comment: Think about it - you have some code executing on a client's machine and you want to know all the files in a directory on a server. No good way to do that other than to ask the server in a formal way e.g. via an API. Unless you mean at client/js compile time or on the client's machine.. bit unclear.

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3663 try this

Comment: Yeah @Dominic this is what I thought about.. But, but.. It should be as simple as possible..

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible because JavaScript runs on the browser, but the files tipically are hosted on a server.
Your server needs to expose an API or any kind of information about the files that are contained in a specific folder, then you can fetch every file using Ajax.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear but the Application is supposed to load images from the server side. This posted helped me alot: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3663 I'm loading Resources from the Public/images folder in my web-app.