# How I can access static files outside the project root?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm developing an app with Electron and React, it's kind of mp3 player. The problem is that I want to play audios that are not in the project folder. How can I upload these files from my hard drive?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Sound from 'react-sound';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Sound
      url='/media/user/Vol/a.mp3'
      playStatus={Sound.status.PLAYING}
      playFromPosition={300}
      onLoading={this.handleSongLoading}
      onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying}
      onFinishedPlaying={this.handleSongFinishedPlaying}
    />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried to set the url like `file:///media/user/Vol/a.mp3`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is the same as is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder

Comment: It's not, my problem is that I need to import files out of the project folder.

Comment: Don't know if it is possible. Most (if not all) browsers prevent it for security reasons. This link asks why JS can't with some good answers. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html. I say JS because TS transpiles to JS, which means TS cannot be better or have more privileges than what it is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply the URL should be like this `E:\folder\musique.mp3` (on windows)

I guess that you allow the user to choose which audio file to play. so first you will do something like this in the main process

```
ipcMain.handle('get-audio', async () => {
    let files = []
    try {
      files = (await dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
      })).filePaths
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    return files
});
```

in the renderer process add a button or something like that with this event

```
const files = await ipcRenderer.invoke('get-audio') 
// update the stats here
```

Then disable web security preference within BrowserWindow

```
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false, // very important 
    }
  });
```

Comment: I alredy have that, the problem is playing a song.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solves my problem, `webSecurity: false`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course Electron can speak to files outside its project root. It wouldn't be any good for making desktop apps if it couldn't.

There are a few ways to do this in Electron.

The [`dialog` API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) lets you present the user with standard File Open dialogs from their OS.

The [`File Object` API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/file-object) lets you speak directly to files on the filesystem.

And the [`shell` API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell) allows you to run native commands, such as launching a native MP3 player.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention one of the main ways you will talk to files outside of the project root: which is via node.js itself.

Comment: Yes, I already get the list of mp3 in a folder that the user selects but what I need is to play it from react, which is what I built the user interface

Comment: You may then need to load the data in node and pass it to Electron, possibly by stream. Have you pursued that direction?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the example you can try in your application

```
//audioFile: path of your audio file
export const playAudio = (audioFile) => {
  if (!audioFile) return;

  if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    let command = `afplay ${audioFile}.aiff`;
    exec(command, (error, _, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        stderr: ${stderr}`);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Try an mp3 file format
    var audio = new Audio(audioFile);
    audio.play();
  }
};
```

Comment: That in my Electron or React sources?

Comment: This can be your helper function and you can call it wherever you need to play audio.