# How to access react public folder in SCSS to import images

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-image

There is folder named 'img' inside public folder.
If I write this,
background: url(img/hero2.jpg) no-repeat center;
Then it throws this error.
Module not found: Can't resolve './img/hero2.jpg' in 'D:\Programming\react\redux-blog\src'

If I write this
background: url(../public/img/hero1.jpg) no-repeat center;
Then it says this.
Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/img/hero1.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an `src/img` folder and place images there.
On the URL then you can use just `background-image: url('/img/hero2.jpg')`.
Webpack will find which images are being used and copy them to a static assets folder. Unused images will not be published, also (depending on your configuration) it can add a unique name to handle properly different versions of the image and bypass proxy caching.

Answer (score 1):

try change

background: url(img/hero2.jpg) no-repeat center;

to (use double slash in path)

background: url('//img/hero2.jpg') no-repeat center;

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `/` in front of path? `background-image: url('/img/hero2.jpg') no-repeat center;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background in sass file use this in component like

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to give a background in a div in react then
use

```
<div style={{"background":"url(pathOfYourImageThatIsStoredInPublicDirectory)"}}>
</div>
```