# React - How to access image that is in public folder?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access an image that is in the public folder inside a js file that is in the src folder? To be more specific, I am styling a div container. I want to set its backgroundImage property to the image file in the public folder. How would I do do that? Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS and images in public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any kind of configuration for this purpose. 
Simply use the regular html tag

```
 <img src= "yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the background-image property of a div container to an image in public folder. How would I write that in code, specifically in a .js file? Thank you for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline style prop and define the background rules.

```
<div style={{
  backgroundImage: "url(pathToFile)",
  // other various style rules to size and position
}} />
```

[image: Edit use local image for background]