# React page is different when using "npm start" and "npm run deploy"

Tags: reactjs, image, github-pages, npm-start, npm-publish

I am building my website and I have issues using npm start to preview images in my web-pages.

When using `npm start` to preview locally my page all the images and videos cannot be found but when I deploy online using github `gh-pages -d build` everything shows just fine.
As you can see no images on localhost: [images and videos missing from my page in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mngnr.jpg)
But once online no issues: [perfectly fine website once online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgyR3.jpg)

I use React to build the website and github-pages to host it online.
All of my images are located in the public folder and since I am a begginer in front-end I did not try anything funny with my compiling.

Any help would be great because not being able to preview images is quite a pain. I could not find anybody with the same issue and I'm a newbie in front-end stuff :/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, would you mind to share some code of your component?

Comment: Hi! here is one example from my code `<section style={{maxWidth: '600px',maxHeight: '300px'}}>
          <SecTitle>Sweet Arpegiato</SecTitle>
          stuff that shows perfectly fine in the preview.
          <img src =  "images/SweetDawn/sweet arp photo.PNG" />
        </section>`

Comment: I guess my issue come from some react-scripts parameters but I have no idea where to look at and I do not want to break it even more. :/ `"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved the issue with this [question about public folder and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder).

The issue came from me not explicitly saying that the images came from the public folder in the image's src and the react-router-dom seemed not to like it.

Writing `<img src =  {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/folder/biking.PNG"} alt = "me on a bike"/>`
instead of `<img src =  {"images/folder/biking.PNG"} alt = "me on a bike"/>` solved my issue.

I still do not know why this works once deployed but not in the "npm start" preview but my problem is solved!