# React: using parameterized routes breaks image URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm developing a small blog app as a portfolio project and have run into something weird.

I have a Blog component mounted at `http://localhost:3000/blog`. Works great. I reference a few images in the ~/public folder, using `src="image.png"`. This becomes `http://localhost:3000/image.png` which finds the image in the public folder as expected.

When I set up another route, to view an individual post, at `http://localhost:3000/blog/1`, it breaks the image link. Instead `src="image.png"` evalutates to `http://localhost:3000/blog/image.png` which doesn't exist. Why is that?

I've seen answers related to using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "image.png"` but that's undefined in my app. (created with 'create-react-app'). I tried making a `.env` file in the root directory with `PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000` but that hasn't done anything. (Yes I restarted the build script.)

As a workaround I created a module containing `export const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';` and am using `baseURL + image.png` but I'm wondering about the 'proper' React way to do this, and why the /blog is inserted into the URL only when the URL contains a parameter.

Here is the main component where I do the routing:

```
const Main = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch location={props.location}>
                    <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog} />
                    <Route path='/blog/:postId' component={Blog} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Redirect to="/home" />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder). Essentially, you should access the public folder in CRA projects with a leading slash (`src="/image.png"`). More broadly speaking, its almost always better to instead keep static images in an `assets` directory inside the `src` directory and import at the top of the file where they are needed for improved error handling and minification.