# cannot display images fetched from backend in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to display images fetched from backend and I am able to display all the data except the images,

Below is the response which I got when I console.log the response,

```
[
{
    "_id": "60a8b70be6384c8052fcc2e0",
    "name": "chan",
    "company": "micro",
    "profile": "uploads\\old.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8b80fe6384c8052fcc2e1",
    "name": "tucker",
    "company": "honda",
    "profile": "uploads\\employee.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8b84be6384c8052fcc2e2",
    "name": "emma",
    "company": "techsoft",
    "profile": "uploads\\girl.png",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8c004e6384c8052fcc2e3",
    "name": "amy",
    "company": "tec in",
    "profile": "uploads\\lady.jpg",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "60a8d07627915c1e2429a8a2",
    "name": "tom",
    "company": "mil tech",
    "profile": "uploads\\tom-hardy.jpg",
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

This is the code I am trying to display images only People.js,

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {startGetPeople} from '../actions/peopleAction'

function People({people:{people}, startGetPeople}){
useEffect(() => {
    startGetPeople()
}, [])
return(
    console.log('from People', people),
    <div className="container">
        <h2>People</h2>
        <ul>
        {
            people.map((people) => {
                return(
                    <li><img src={people.profile} style={{width: '30px', height: '30px'}}/></li>
                )
            })
        }
        </ul>
    </div>
 )
 }
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 people: state.people
 })
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {startGetPeople})(People)
```

And my structure of my directory is here

project-> uploads-> images

project-> client-> src-> components-> People.js

Comment: It seems like `client` is a `react` project and you are trying to access the files outside project. Move your uploads folder to react project's public folder and check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder)

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this? You'll just need to replace `\\` with `\` and use relative paths `../../../${people.profile}` in your case, or if you have an alias to your `src` folder you can use that with something like `@/people.profile`

Comment: Does the HTTP gets placed to fetch the image or is the call not triggered at all?

Comment: The call is triggered and I am getting the response

Comment: I tried adding relative path too like this ../../../${people.profile} but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access files that are out of you project `baseUrl`. `baseUrl` is determined by `package.json`, so in most cases it's (unless you will change it, but you cannot level up from there anyway) `/src`. You should move your images somewhere in `src`, e.g. `project/client/src/upload/images`.

Additionally, looks like this path `uploads\\employee.png` has incorrect separator, it should be more like this `\/` instead of `\\`. Anyway you can easy replace it by `profile.replace(/\\/, '\/')`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are served locally in `react.js` you can either do it as follows:

```
import image from '../project/images/image.png'

....

<img src={image} alt="demo"/>
```

OR:

```
<img src={window.require('../project/images/image.png')} alt="demo"/>

OR
<img src={require('../project/images/image.png')} alt="demo"/>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am not having images locally but I am fetching it from the backend.  Thanks for your response