# referencing an image in public folder react js

Tags: reactjs

This is driving me slightly mad. I've searched all around and think I am doing everything right...But clearly am not!

All I'm trying to do is set a bg image from a picture in my public folder, but it keeps throwing an error!

(see below, code with folder tree and error message)

Even the greyed out code on line 10 does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks from the #noobcoder,
ClaaziX

[image: relating code]

[image: error message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)

Comment: It does not! Same error, it's just not finding the image! :(

Comment: Any idea on why the error should root from `RainDrops.module.css` as stated in the stacktrace? What does this CSS file look like?

Comment: because I was trying t call the bgimage in css as well!

Comment: For me, currently it looks like this is the error but not your `img` in `index.js`.

Comment: you were right!

Comment: well...no error messages, but no bg img either! #facepalm

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes from `RainDrops.module.css`, but to answer your actual question regarding images in public folder, you can reference them without using the environment variable. This was also answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder).

Your code should look like this:

```js
<img alt="Lightning" src="/images/Lightning.jpg" />
```

Comment: I just get this:

./pages/index.js
Error: error: Expected ',', got 'alt'
  
   |
18 |         <img alt="Lightning" src="/images/Lightning.jpg">
   |              ^^^

Comment: I may have missed the closing forward slash in the closing tag of the `img`. Can you try again?

Comment: same errror! :(

Comment: actually that worked...localhost just wasn't refreshing! But the same thing doesn't work for a background image! import background from "/images/Lightning.jpg"; throws an error!

Answer (score 0):

By defaul your public folder is accessible anywhere in your code just reference it like this below, change your `image src` to something like this

```
<img src='/images/Lightning.jpg'/>
```

Comment: I just get this:

Comment: ./pages/index.js
Error: error: Expected ',', got 'alt'
  
   |
18 |         <img alt="Lightning" src="/images/Lightning.jpg">
   |              ^^^

Comment: add alt="Lightning"  to the image tag