# Importing images from public folder in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, create-react-app

OK last hail mary here. I've seen this question a lot but no clear answer. I moved all of my images out of my `src` folder to my `public` folder into a sub-folder `images`. And used the URL like `./images/my-image.png` but the image isn't populating. I am using create-react-app. How do I call images from a `public` folder outside of my `src` folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS and images in public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the src from `/public/images` to `/images`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```js
src:(process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/images/image-name.jpg")
```