# How to insert images from public folder into a card in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have an array of objects in App.js and I need to create cards out of them using my CardItem-component.js.
Here is CardItem-component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Card} from "react-bootstrap";

const CardItemComponent = (props) =>{

    const addItem = () =>{
        console.log(props.card);
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <Card>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.card.imgurl}/>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{props.card.name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                        <strong>${props.card.price}</strong>
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="success" onClick={addItem}>Add</Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </div>
    </>
    );
};

export default CardItemComponent;
```

And this is App.js.

```
import './App.css';
import CardItemComponent from './components/card-item-component/CardItem-component';
import { propTypes } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Image';

function App() {
  const itemsList = [
    {id: 1, name: "An apartment in San-Francisco", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-vecislavas-popa-1571460.jpg/", price: 20000},
    {id: 2, name: "An apartment in San-Diego", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-pixabay-276724.jpg", price: 150000},
    {id: 3, name: "An apartment in New York", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-pixabay-271624.jpg", price: 30000},
    {id: 4, name: "A house in California", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-curtis-adams-5008389.jpg", price: 35000},
    {id: 5, name: "A house in Florida", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-curtis-adams-8583638.jpg", price: 22000},
    {id: 6, name: "A house in Connecticut", imgurl: "/imgs/apartments/pexels-ron-lach-10397920.jpg", price: 20000}
  ];

  return (
    <section className="app">
      <main>
        <section className="mt-container">
          <div className="row">
            {
              itemsList.map(item=>{
                return(
                  <CardItemComponent key={item.id} card={item}/>
                );
              })
            }
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Text and buttons are displayed properly but pictures are not shown at all. Currenctly it looks like this[image] What are the possible fixes?

Comment: In the CardItem-Component.js  you wrote 'scr' instead of **src**. Does it work after fixing it?

Comment: @Tehila thank you! It helped a bit. At least now it looks as if there has to be an image. I have updated my post and included a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like duplicate of below question

[ReactJS and images in public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196800/reactjs-and-images-in-public-folder)

and as per this you can use either one to use image from public folder

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/yourPathHere.jpg'} />
```

or

```
<img src="/image.jpg" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Import image like this

```
import img from "/imgs/apartments/pexels-vecislavas-popa-1571460.jpg/";
```

then assign `img` to `imgUrl`

```
 {id: 1, name: "An apartment in San-Francisco",
 imgurl: img, price: 20000};
```

Comment: Nice, I just figured it out to. This is the way you always need to import images in React.