# Local image not loading in React

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Very new to storing local assets on React.

I've configured webpack with file-loader and image-loader and stored the images locally, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be showing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WorkItem from './work-item';
import WorkItemsArray from './work-items-array';

class Work extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id='work'>
        <h1>Work</h1>
        <img src={require('../images/weatherImg.png')}/>
        <div id='portfolio'>
          {WorkItemsArray.map(({ url, img, title, description, github }) => {
            return (
              <WorkItem
                key={title}
                url={url}
                img={img}
                title={title}
                description={description}
                github={github}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Work;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[name]_[hash:7].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              // the webp option will enable WEBP
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ]
};
```

[image: Folder directory tree]

FWIW, I'm not getting any errors at all, just that the image doesn't seem to be loading.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the url rendered in browser? Wat happens when you go the url in a new tab ? any network error while transfer ?

Comment: the url is `/images/weatherImg_6281b3f.png` and when I goto that url in a new tab i just get a blank black screen show up. When I goto the network tab I get a status 304

Comment: Unrelated but it is ideal to not use a `class` when there is not state to manage in the component. Just use a simple `function()`

Comment: Hope this answer will help you out.
[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783390/11225762)

Answer (score 1):

Since you assumed you didn't get any error, you have two possibilities: -

1. Either the image is not visible (maybe because of height and width are small)
2. Or the whole component `<Work />` is not rendered, or even rendered, it is then unmounted without detecting the same.

For the first, force a specific size to the image or replace another image: -

```
    <img src={require('../images/weatherImg.png')} width="400" height="500"/>
```

For the second, add a `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and debug, then check the browser console: -

```
  class Work extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(new Date(), ' Work is mouned ');
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log(new Date(), ' Work will be killed ');
    }
    render() {
      //...
    }
  }
```

Comment: I added `width='400' height='500'` and i can see the outline of the image, but it's a broken image. And when I put in the console logs, it's calling `componentDidMount()` but not `componentWillUnmount()`

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have your `images` folder inside the `public` folder.

try:

> `<img src={require(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/dog.png")}`

for others, if you aren't using webpack try:

> `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/dog.png"}`