# reactjs image doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs

I have a local image that I want to put on my webpage built in react. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images) but it didn't help me. My code is as following:

```
const right={
    float:"right",
    fontSize:"18px"
}

export default class CloseUpCam extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="closeupcam" style={right}>
            <div>CLOSEUP CAMERA</div>
            <img src={require('./img/hand.png')} width="70" height="50" alt="cam"/>
        </div>
    )}}
```

There's no error messages. The picture just doesn't show up. Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think its because of the require.

Comment: @JaisonJustus How?

Comment: Like this - `<img src="/img/hand.png" width="70" height="50" alt="cam"/>` ?

Comment: @JaisonJustus That's definitely not working. I believe I need that require because of webpack. I used Vuejs before and I needed that require for adding images to my webpage. I just don't know what I did wrong with react

Comment: If you import the image (e.g. import imgVar from ' ./img/hand.jpg') and then write <img src={imgVar}/> does it help? If not, change the image name to a non existent image. Do you get an error? If you do, I guess that it means that the first import worked and the problem is in the <img src>

Comment: @Rahamin It doesn't help to change to import. And yes it does give an error if I used a non-existant image name. How do I fix it?

Comment: So the problem is not in the import command, but in the img src... strange. No idea. Sorry

Comment: The only idea I have is to start a new project with create-react-app and insert there the image and this component only, maybe it works. Your code seems fine.

Answer (score 9):

In react you must import your image file like all other files

```js
import Image from "./img/hand.png";

const right = {
    float: "right",
    fontSize: "18px"
};

export default class CloseUpCam extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="closeupcam" style={right}>
                <div>CLOSEUP CAMERA</div>
                <img src={Image} width="70" height="50" alt="cam"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your way of show image actually do  work in React,I think its the matter of your path of the pic.Do you put all your static files under the public folder,or how do you manage your static pages?

```
<img src={require('./img/hand.png')} width="70" height="50" alt="cam"/>
```

Comment: This picture is in the same sub-folder of src as my js file.

Comment: Do you use create-react-app to create your app? wepack has a limit for the size of the pic. If the pic exceed the size in the config file,then it will not be packed. Maybe you can check it.

Comment: Oh. What's the limit in size?

Comment: I found that the limit of size is 2MB, but my picture is only 39KB.

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images?answertab=active#tab-top. It is the same problem with you.

Comment: I didn't see anything that could help in this question.

Comment: em,you can check your console first,then see whether it loads the pic sucessfullly?

Comment: I don't see anything in my console that is related to this particular js file.

Answer (score 1):

Put the images in the public folder of react app and try

`<img className="" alt="Tag" src="/assets/images/tag.svg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in the public folder of react app and try

```
    const right={
        float:"right",
        fontSize:"18px"
    }

    export default class CloseUpCam extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="closeupcam" style={right}>
                <div>CLOSEUP CAMERA</div>
                <img src="/imagename.jpg" width="70" height="50" alt="cam"/>
            </div>
        )}}
```

Here is a working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q3y7v69p6)

Comment: I tried this and the result is the same. It doesn't work for me. Still, no error message.

Comment: Yes. If the path is not correct, there will be an error message. I tried.

Comment: can you put the image in the public folder and try again,i will edit the code

Comment: I got an error: failed to compile. Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/hand.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: @Young I have added a working sample in codesandbox,please do check

Comment: @Young you don't need to import image if it is put in public folder

Comment: It's the same, the picture still doesn't show up even if I put it in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put your images into your **public** folder.