# Can't use require() method that receives a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As part of a personal project, I have to create an image gallery. For every image (miniature) that is clicked in the gallery, I want the chosen image to appear in a larger size on the page. I have been trying to do this by passing the desired image's address as a prop to my ImageOnView component, like so:

```
<ImageOnView imgSrc = {this.state.imageLarge}/>
```

Inside my ImageOnView component, however, I'm having trouble displaying the image using the require() method. Right now it looks like this:

```
class ImageOnView extends Component {
  render() {
    //This alert displays the image source as expected
    alert(this.props.imgSrc);
    return (
      <img id = "image-large" src = {require(this.props.imgSrc)}/>
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following error on my webpage: "Error: Cannot find module ".""

How do I go about resolving this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using `require()`? Just `src={this.props.imgSrc}` should be enough

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.imageLarge` in the parent component?

Comment: External images load just fine, but I have to use require() for local images since I am using Webpack. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice a local image's address, with quotes included, like so: imageLarge: "\"./images/sala-small/04_sl02_SS.jpg\""

Comment: Did you try without the quotes inside the string?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, to no success.

Comment: @RodrigoVeiga you can try doing `require('' + this.props.imgSrc)`

Comment: Did you try instead of passing the variable passing a simple string with the image path? I have used this in that way and it works with no issues ... but not as a variable for the path.

Answer (score 3):

Just try

```
src={require('' + this.props.imgSrc)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Webpack as a bundler in runtime, `require` can't use a variable name like this. It should accept a resolvable path, ie a string here. So, you can `require` the image in the parent instead of the child and use the resolved path:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    imageLarge: require( "./somedir/some.jpg" ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageOnView imgSrc={this.state.imageLarge} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ImageOnView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // This alert displays the image source as expected
    alert( this.props.imgSrc );
    return (
      <img id="image-large" src={this.props.imgSrc} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also do like this:-

```
import React from 'react';

function index({title, image, rating}) {
   return <div>
     <img alt="img" src={require("" + image)}></img>
   </div>;
}

export default index;
```

Answer (score -1):

require() is used to import a module or file. So to get an imageLarge from another file you might want to

```
const imageLarge = require(path)
```

or es6 version:

```
import imageLarge from 'path'
```

in the img tag you just need to provide a src attribute with imageLarge in component it would look something like:

```
const imageLarge = require(path) 

<ImageOnView imgSrc = {imageLarge}/>

class ImageOnView extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <img id = "image-large" src = {this.props.imgSrc}/>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: OP explained `require` is needed due to local images and webpack.