# Img src not loading in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

```
<img src="play.jpg" alt="play"></img>
```

Works perfectly in regular HTML but not in React. Is the only way to do it is add it as a background?

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors? If i had to guess i would say the relative path has changd but it's hard to tell from what you have provided..

Comment: can we see more of your code? Where is the jpg being stored in relation to your component that is trying to display it?

Comment: @Ado figured it out. React has to `require()` local images for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `<img src={require('./play.jpg')} />` ?
check out this question [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

Comment: It's working now. Thank you, sir. You win the internet today.