# How to keep pictures after refreshing page on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dom

React app working but after refreshing the page, the images became not visible...

Demo: https://demo-old.herokuapp.com

The issue is discussed(see link below): [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images) and that was recommended to use:

```
<img src={require('./funnyanimal.gif')} />
```

Instead of:

```
<img src={"./funnyanimal.gif"} />
```

But it was not compiling and producing the error as below:

Error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './funnyanimal.gif' in '/app/src'
```

Comment: something is wrong with your router. also try assigning key to your image tags
<img src={require('./funnyanimal.gif')} key="1"/>
<img src={require('./funnyanimal.gif')} key="2"/>
.
.
.
unique key to all images

Comment: Try adding the correct relative path to the image. or if you are using ES6 then import your image and use it as a source.

Comment: Can I add. trying just with one button?<img src={require('./funnyanimal.gif')} key="1"/>

Comment: I keep all images under public.dir and they all visible until I click on them and refresh page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of problem:

The images were not visible after refreshing the page because on the main page the link was to ./funnyanimal.gif but after refreshing the page that is being on a route, then you link to (for ex. to the first image) is ./one/funnyanimal.gif which is not there - that why all images became not visible.

The solution:

I  removed the dot from all the img. tags and make them: `<img src={"/funnyanimal.gif"} />` instead `<img src={"./funnyanimal.gif"} />`  This way the link was made to the absolute path and not to the relative one to the route; therefore, after refreshing a page the images would not disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem you have to add [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) to your webpack configuration.

**Installation:**

First, run this command to install the package:

```
npm i -D file-loader
```

Then, add this config to your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    ...
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Usage:**

```
import image from './picture.png';

...

<img src={image} />
```

Comment: I don't think that i have webpack.config.js. or server.js?
what need to be instead of ... in your code?

Comment: @TM Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: what do you mean? I've create react app. there are:git, package-son, public, node-modules, src directories..

Comment: @TM Run `npm run eject` then you can find webpack config files.

Comment: So, first:  npm i -D file-loader, second: npm run eject  and then:add this config   Is It right?

Comment: What about those plural dots ... in your answer? left them as is/substitute them?

Comment: @TM No, they aren't substituting. I mean is place the config after your configs (don't replace all of them)

Comment: Not: it the same. I've done 1,2 step but new mirror version want not go through: errors whith this command: npm install -g npm
and I don't have webpack.config.js.  Where it supposed to be?  Should I repeat those 2 steps/do something different?

Comment: I've repeated step1 but not proceed in step 2 with ejection since I've done this earlier...

on screen as below:

react-scripts eject

NOTE: Create React App 2 supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

? Are you sure you want to eject? This action is permanent. No
Close one! Eject aborted.

Comment: It doesn't work even so i've made changes in web pack.conf under/demo-old/node_modules/react-scripts/config: no images after refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

Add a unique key to each item in the list. Check the web console inspector, and fix those errors.

More info here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

```
index.js:1452 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

    in ul (at Six.js:15)
    in Six (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:113)
    in div (at App.js:112)
    in div (at App.js:95)
    in div (at App.js:28)
    in div (at App.js:19)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:18)
    in AppRouter (at src/index.js:7)
```