# How to set image url in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the path of an Image inside a `img` tag in `ReactJS` but It is not showing...

This is what I tried...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.css";

export default class CarouselComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Carousel
        showArrows
        emulateTouch
        infiniteLoop
        autoPlay
        interval={2000}
        onChange={this._onChange}
        onClickItem={this._onClickItem}
        onThumbClick={this._onClickThumb}
      >
        <div>
    <img src="../images/sample1.jpg" /> {/*not working*/}
          <p className="legend">Welcome to W.W Coders</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x300?" />
          <p className="legend">Faculty of Computing</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x300?" />
          <p className="legend">Faculty of Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x300?" />
          <p className="legend">Faculty of Business Management</p>
        </div>
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

Can someone tell me where I have went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference a local image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using webpack or a similar bundler for your code compilation, you can use the file-loader to ensure that the image is copied to the compile folder, and you get the path pointing to it as such:

```
import imagePath from '../images/sample.jpg'

...

<img src={imagePath} />
```

Answer (score 1):

From your project structure, it looks like the `public` folder is where you should put all your images. Any files that are accessible by url directly (like images), should be inside this folder. The files inside `src` and other folders are intended to be built/compiled and not directly accessed via a URL.

You should move your `images` folder to be inside the `public` folder. So it would be like:

```
/public/images/sample1.jpg
```

Then you would access it like:

```
src="/images/sample1.jpg"
```

Assuming you are using `create-react-app` here's [some info about the `public` folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder). It looks like they want you to use a variable for the path, but often you can just use the root (`/`).