# (React) PNG Image will import, but won't display

Tags: reactjs, image, import

I'm trying to create a helper function that will return one of two images-- either a check mark or a red error icon, depending on user input.

My header code looks like this

```
import ErrorImage from './../Assets/Error.png'
import CheckMark from './../Assets/CheckMark.png'
```

My helper function looks like this:

```
   if(myVar){
return <img src={CheckMark} alt='CheckMark'/>
}
else{
return <img src={ErrorImage} alt='Error'/>
}
```

I'm positive that I'm importing both correctly-- they're in the same relative file path, and came from the same page source. The weird thing is, only the red x will load. The check mark is showing up as a blank image when I try to follow the path in inspect element. However, when I open the check mark in my assets folder, I get the check mark that I'd expect to see.

For reference, I'm using [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/TqDzm8AkkqdvFdAs7) image for the check mark and [this](http://clipartbarn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Triangle-with-exclamation-point-clipart.png) image for the error icon.

I've tried setting the height and width to arbitrarily large numbers, just to make sure that I'm not creating an image with 0 size, and I've set the opacity to 1, in case it was transparent for some reason. Neither of these made the image appear.

All I can think of is that it must be a property of the image that is causing this issue, but I've tried four or five different check mark images, and none of them have worked. I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly, and all of the supporting documentation I've found has been for improperly importing the data. So far as I can tell, I'm importing this data correctly.

Edit: One weird element that I've noticed. If I console.log my error icon, I get a long string of text beginning with "data: image/png.base64...." If I console.log my checkmark, I get "static/media/Checkmark.89156a.png" and that's it. I have much, MUCH more data for the error icon than the checkmark.

Edit 2: I still don't know what caused this issue, but I just abandoned trying to import images and swapped over to using Unicode symbols, and that's working for me without issue.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a sandbox?

Comment: I created a code sandbox, and unfortuantely it works without error in code sandbox. I have no idea why I cannot recreate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was one of permissions, I believe. As I eventually learned, if I said

```
const checkMark = require('./../Assets/checkMark.png')
```

I could load the checkMark. It's a function of webPack. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images) post explains it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some syntax errors in your code

The header should be:

```js
import ErrorImage from './../Assets/Error.png'
import CheckMark from './../Assets/CheckMark.png'
```

The helper function should be:

```js
if(myVar){
  return <img src={CheckMark} alt='CheckMark'/>
}
else{
  return <img src={ErrorImage} alt='Error'/>
}
```

See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react) for more details

Comment: Unfortunately the two typos you spotted were just typos I made while writing in my code (I have one computer for internet and another for coding, so I can't copy paste). The code on my development machine is identical to what you've written, and does not run.

Comment: You mentioned only the red x appearing, is this the `ErrorImage` you are referring to?


Also have you tried using the same image for both conditions of the if? Perhaps your `myVar` is not what you expect

Comment: I have tried using the error image for both, and I have confirmed that the conditional statement is functioning as expected. If I change the CheckMark image to be ErrorImage, it will return the error image without issue.

Comment: I'm assuming you wish for the `CheckMark` image to be displayed, have you tried using `CheckMark` for both of the images? Double check that the file exists at the path location and do a chrome inspect on the webpage when it loads. You will want to check the console output for any error messages that might be helpful

Comment: I've tried using checkmark for both images.

When i try to inspect it in Chrome, I get a blank image. I'm not sure what is causing a blank image. When I explore in my file explorer, I see a green check mark.

Comment: Regarding why that error message displays the data URI as a [base64 string](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) 

Honestly I'm kinda stumped, it seems to be a webpack issue you're having. If you go to chrome inspect > sources then try file the file in question, see if it exists.

Comment: I'm using the webpack that came with create-react-app, and I haven't done anything to modify it on my own. 

Regardless, I wound up just using a unicode alert symbol/check mark rather than using clipart, and that seems to be working now.