# How to show dummy image in React when url is broken?

Tags: reactjs, image, onclick, dummy-variable, fallback

My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loaded: false,
    error: false
  }

  onImageLoad = () => {
    this.setState({
      loaded: true
    })
  }

  onImageError = () => {
    this.setState({
      error: true
    });

  }

  render() {
    // let imgSrc = (!error) ? src: fallbackSrc
    return (
     <div>
        <img src= {'https://unsplash.com/photos/wQLAGv4_OYs'} alt={'Wresting Character'} onLoad={() => this.onImageLoad()} onError={require('../src/images/batista.jpg')} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default App;
```

> I want to show the fallback image if the url is broken. Right now the default image shows but if I change the url of it the page throws an error. How do I get to show the dummy image incase if my link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can fallback to default image once the error occurs:

```
onImageError = (ev) => {
  this.setState({
    error: true
  });
  ev.target.src = 'some default image url';
}
```

Comment: It throws an error after I change the  default image url to an incorrect one. Which is this https://imgur.com/a/wQxBH5N

Comment: @VishalMishra it needs to be a URL, not a file path

Comment: @Jason It is a url which I have saved in src and fallbacSrc. Please check above

Comment: no, those are file paths, not URLs that are accessible by your web server

Comment: you are changing the the path of the image that you use in the 'import' statement. You cannot pass the building process when you are importing a none existing file.

Comment: Okay so this is what I have done. What is wrong here?  https://imgur.com/a/8trJG9c

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors) attribute on the `img` tag.  You can define a handler for the error, and replace the target source attribute with your fallback URL.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as I am using it on the image tag itself as of now.

Comment: you would return the URL you want to use, not the file path.  You've defined the file path to the image as part of the `Batista` and `Game` imports, but those are not accessible via a URL.  eg, you need something like `/image/assets/someimage.jpg`

Comment: I tried but this does not seem to work. Sharing a screenshot of the same https://imgur.com/a/8trJG9c

Comment: don't use `require`.  use the actual URL path.  eg `src="/image/assets/triple_h.jpg"`

Comment: It does not work without require. Here is where I found require from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images

Comment: ok, so its a local image, not one that's available elsewhere.  Check the second answer for that question.

Comment: You cannot test your app with an error image that is loaded using import. You need to pass a valid URL that returns no image. 
What you are doing now is similar to importing a non-existing class/package/file. It will throw a build error.
You can ONLY import/require existing files.

Comment: @dimagolovin alright so I have removed the import. I have updated my question. Please have a look and guide me. Thanks