# Image not able to load react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

**Here is my `<img>` tag**

```
  <li className="dropdown user user-menu">
                                <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <img src="/public/assets/images/user2-160x160.jpg" className="user-image" alt="User Image" />
                                        <span className="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
                                </a>
<li/>
```

**This is my structure**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

Comment: Can you show where the <img> calling component resides in heirarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are in the public folder Like my folder structure :

```
"/assets/images/user2-160x160.jpg"
```

in your `<img>` src instead of importing

```
'../../public/assets/images/user2-160x160.jpg';
```

This will work

```
<img className="user-image"  src="/assets/images/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User Image" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the image at the top as you would any other module! ( assuming you got modules enabled in typescript and then just pass it is as a variable to jsx:

```
import myimage from "./../.../path/images/user2-160x160.jpg";
...

 <img alt="media-icon-link" className="media-icon-link" src={myimage} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Same with above answer, As far as I know you can use require api like this

```js
<img alt="media-icon-link" className="media-icon-link" src={require("./../.../path/images/user2-160x160.jpg")} />
```

It's just depends on your taste