# Displaying folder of images in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

Currently, I have some code that is able to set a variable to be the same name as one of the import statements that call the images. I was trying to find a way to then use this to display the image. My code looks at some data and comes out with a name, say 'Bill', and assigns it to name. It would then try to show the image with the following code:

```
<img src={name} alt ='' />
```

instead of using

```
<img src={Bill} alt ='' />
```

I have an import statement at the top that is 'import Bill from *path*' and this is able to produce the bottom statement, but I would like for it to display with the variable. Let me know if this is too confusing so I can explain it better or you need more code and I could provide.

Added some better code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Bill from '../../img/players/Bill.jpg'
import Grant from '../../img/players/Grant.jpg'


const CharacterItem = ({ info, index }) => {
    var name = info[index][0].last_name
    console.log(name) //outputs Bill
    console.log(name === Bill) //outputs false
    return (
        <img src={'../../img/players/' + name} alt ='' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of the file just provide the path as a string.

`<img src={"./path/" + name} alt ='' />`

If this doesn't solve your problem providing code or a better explanation can help.

Comment: I actually already tried this out and it didn't work. I added more code above and explained how some of the code outputted in the console as. If I take out the name and instead put Bill inside the quotes it doesn't work also so it only works when I type in just Bill without the full path.

Comment: I tried '../../img/players/Armstrong.jpg' in src and '../../img/players/'+name+'.jpg' and both of them didn't work out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583854/10746985, 99% sure this is it then.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because of the module bundler such as webpack which uses file-loader that outputs image files and returns paths when the images are imported.

Take a look at this https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

`<img />` tag `src` will refer to relative urls only if the path is for bundled static files in browser.