# When I add an image to my app it doesnt show up

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

1. I referenced and image as  `<img src="public/assets/images/sydney.jpg" alt=""/>`
2. I put my jpg image in `public/assets/images` folder.
3. I then build successfully with `npm start`, however,  when I go onto my site the image isn't there.
   Please comment if you need any more information. Here are some    screenshots

Thanks

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpc8e.png)

[Here is the app, I want the image to appear in the Sydney FC Box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg7Pl.png)

```
import React from 'react';
```

```html
import React from 'react';

export const ALeagueTeam = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <section id="one" class="tiles">
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                    <img src="public/assets/images/sydney.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">SYDNEY FC</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN 2004</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 1st</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">MELBOURNE CITY</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 2ND</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">WELLINGTON PHOENIX</a></h3>
                        <p>FOUNDED IN </p>
                    </header>
                </article>
                <article>
                                    <span class="image">
                                        <img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>
                    <header class="major">
                        <h3><a href="landing.html" class="link">VIEW PLAYERS</a></h3>
                        <p>CURRENTLY 3RD</p>
                    </header>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to move the code from the image into the question? This site has a code block system that you can use. It's this symbol { } when you are editing/posting a question

Comment: @TheGrandJ there is the code :) "<img src="public/assets/images/sydney.jpg" alt=""/>
                                    </span>" that part

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Create React App build system, then you have two options.

#1 Use import statement at the top

```
import logo from './logo.png';
```

then

```
return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
```

#2 Use public folder and use environment variable to substitute in the path during build

```
return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
```

Both are explained [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) and [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder)

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve './sydney.jpg' in 'C:\Users\danie\my-app\src\components\ALeagueTeam'  ??

Comment: The image needs to be local to the source file. If you're using method #1, then the image cannot be in the public folder. Also to verify, you did start this project with npx create-react-app right? Cause other build systems have different behaviors.

Comment: Yes I believe i did start it with that? Do you have discord can i push u my code?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, that is html not react so instead of

**HTML**:

```
<img src="/images/sydney.jpg" alt=""/>
```

you need to use:

**REACT**:

```
<img src={require('../images/sydney.jpg')} />
```

replacing image-name.png with the correct image name for each of them. That way the image is able to work properly. Also don't put the img on the public Also it is a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images). Good Luck

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219530/discussion-on-answer-by-xatifx-when-i-add-an-image-to-my-app-it-doesnt-show-up).