# React.js project local images suddenly stopped loading

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

So I have a React.js project that suddenly doesn't load local images (such as: `src={require("../../assets/images/logo/logo-v4.png")}` on localhost. Remote images from an external URL are displaying. Looks like my live deployed build still loads the images properly, but I am worried to build and deploy my recent changes to corrupt my live build with whatever this issue is. I have tried to `git checkout` an older commit where I know the images were working properly, but that checkout is also not displaying local images.

I have tried deleting `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, `npm cache clean --force`, then `npm install` again, and the problem still persists. I have reset my PC. I have run other React.js projects on my PC and local images load just fine, so it is just with this specific project.

Not sure how this happened, or what to try next to resolve this issue. Has this happened to anyone else? What else can I try to resolve this? Let me know if you want me to share more code. Thanks!

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.13.0",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.14.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "npm": "^7.0.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-animated-burgers": "^1.2.8",
    "react-animated-slider": "^1.1.4",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.9.0",
    "react-datez": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.3",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-pdf": "^5.0.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-responsive": "^6.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.1.0",
    "recharts": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had that happen in debug builds several times, but it works just fine on release builds. Could you test that?

Comment: Also, you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images

Comment: Correct, that's what I was saying that it still seems to work on my live deployed build, but the link main answer is just to use `require()`, but that's not the issue here. Is there something else you are referring to with that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I troubleshooted today and narrowed down the issue to updating `react-scripts` to the latest version which is v4.0.0, so I downgraded to v3.4.4, and the local images loaded properly. I will open an issue on the react-scripts GitHub page!

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal import `import logo from '../../assets/images/logo/logo-v4.png'` it should work. For some reasons require is importing images as modules.