# Issues with importing images for ReactJS App

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Created an app with `create-react-app` and tailwindcss. I am trying to display local images in my website. I created this folder structure in src: `assets/media/images/profile.jpg`. The image is not displayed in browser. Here's what I am doing.

Here's the component in `src/components/Hero.js`:

```
import ImageOne from '../assets/media/images/profile.jpg';

const Hero = () => {
return (
    <div className="bg-white h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <h1 className="lg:text-9xl md:text-7xl sm:text-5xl text-3xl font-black mb-14">
            Text
        </h1>

        <img class="rounded" src={ImageOne} alt='Profile'/>
        
    </div>
)
}

export default Hero
```

The image is simply not displayed. Here's what the browser is loading: `<img class="rounded" src="/static/media/profile.ba8339ef.jpg" alt="Profile">`

Other stackoberflow answers, like [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images), did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double-check all instructions in the tailwind guide, make sure you replaced `react-scripts start` by `craco start`:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

in the meantime, have a look at this example repository:

https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/2021-03-18-tailwindcss-and-create-react-app

I created an `assets/media/images/profile.jpg` and `src/components/Hero.js` with the same snippet you shared here, and it is working correctly

Comment: I've been following this tutorial since I am new to these technologies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiGmAI5e91M&t=615s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia, and I have not used ```craco start```. In package.json, scripts, my start looks like this: ```"start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start"```, with watch being: ```"watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"```

Comment: Implemented your suggestions, no luck. Pulled the github repo, and I find out that the problem was with the actual file that I was importing :)

Answer (score 2):

Move your images folder from src/assets/media/ to public/ and add :

```
<img class="rounded" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/profile.jpg'} alt='Profile'/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. This is what the browser loads ```<img class="rounded" src="/images/profile.jpg" alt="Profile">```. No image is displayed still.

Comment: @BogdanAndrei I don't know Tailwind, you should try oieduardobelo's solution, it seems to be the right one. Look here -> https://blog.logrocket.com/create-react-app-and-tailwindcss/ and https://dev.to/shaan71845/setup-your-reactjs-tailwind-css-project-by-creating-a-template-2ifa