# React unable to display images from local path

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, I'm trying to display images from the **src/images** folder.
but after inserting the correct path, then also the image is not visible.
[Here you can see my img tag path and on the left side folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S83eG.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

Comment: did you made an import? like `import image from '../images/myimage.png'` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the Image you provided, looks like you used `require("path...")` which is not a good way to do so, its valid tho, but not a good practice, its recommended and is common to use `import X from "somewhere"` syntax.

I suggest you to use either of these two ways to use images in react.

1. put images in `public` folder and use relative links in the `href` tag, i.e:

```html
<img href="/images/panda.png" alt="cute panda" />
```

2. put images inside a folder somewhere inside `src` folder *like you did in the image* and import images using ES import syntax, and use imported image variable in `{}` expression for `src` prop, i.e:

```js
import PandaImg from "../images/panda.png"

const Panda = ()=>{
  return <img src={PandaImg} alt="cute panda" />
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/images-in-react-3qbeq?file=/src/App.js) Example may help you further explore the code in broader context.