# React SSR load static image wrong path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

i have React SSR app. I have folder's structure like this:

[image]

I have static express middleware which handles my static and images in  tag
on client it works correctly:

[image]

But when i try to get ssr (renderToPipeableStream) my app i have path to my image like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/d167bb73efa5dba9019c.png
```

How can i configure it to start processing photos in the static folder?

Express middleware:

```
const server = express();

server.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this

1. [link 1](https://joshraiborde.medium.com/react-images-not-loading-1c103029526a)
2. [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

I think you need to add this code to your Webpack config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I have an image loader, the problem is that the image is requested from the localhost:3000 url on the server, but the images are stored in the static folder. i want to solve the problem with the paths

Comment: oh, I think you need to add `"homepage": "./"` line in the `package.json` file.
Tell me if this works.

Comment: I tried, It isn't

Comment: can you send me your dist folder and your the root folder ?