# When I link JS script with HTML I get error: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, operating-system, require

I have an application written in the electron module. When I add a script from a JS file to an html file or enter a script between <script> tags and define a new module, I get an error: **ReferenceError: require is not defined**

This is my HTML script:
`<script src="../scripts/computer.js"></script>`

This is the javascript file:
`const os = require("os")`

I wanted to fetch information from my computer and then display it in my application using the "os" module but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe package.json have `module` type specified - try `import os from 'os'`

Comment: Related, if Electron doesn't add `require` (and access to things like `os`) to the render process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Normally for getting such access to os data you should used the main process so put code inside you entry point script (main.js or index.js depending of what you put inside you package.json file). You would better have a deep look inside the Electron docs. Anyway if you want to "require" in your renderer process (your case computer.js) as require is in the node world you should declare in the webPreferences of your main Window nodeIntegration to true and contextIsolation to false. They are not advised setting for security but could be solution to start to get how the processes communicate.

Answer (score 0):

`require` is not native for browser, it is a part of `Node.js`

there is a good explanation in the answer to this post

[how to use react require syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248012/how-to-use-react-require-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      ...
      nodeIntegration: true
      ...
    })
```

You can add 'nodeIntegration: true' to your window attribute in main.js